# Shared module variables in ruby

Tags: ruby

I was wondering whether or not is was possible to create shared variables between classes which include the same module:

```
module Module1

  @@shared

  class NestedClass1

   def initialize
     @@shared = "hello world"
   end

   def foo
     p @@shared
   end

  end

end

module Module1

  class NestedClass2

     def bar
       p @@shared
     end

  end
end

foo = Module1::NestedClass1.new
bar = Module1::NestedClass2.new

foo.bar
# => "hello world"
bar.bar
# => "hello world"
```

?

Comment: Your classes don't include any modules.

Comment: @Nicolay, the answer to your question is 'yes', but it's a little unclear what exactly you're trying to do. Do you have a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `@@shared` at the top has no effect. `@@shared` is defined for `Foo` because it appears in `initialize`. `@@shared` is not define for `Bar`. Note `foo.class.class_variables #=> [:@@shared]`, `bar.class.class_variables #=> []`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing namespace and including a module. It is possible to share a class variable if you **actually** include a shared module, and **actually** initialize the class variable. And it will not cause an error if you **not use an undefined method** `NestedClass1#bar` but use a defined method `NestedClass1#foo`.

```
module Module1
  @@shared = nil
end

class NestedClass1
  include Module1
  def initialize
    @@shared = "hello world"
  end
  def foo
    p @@shared
  end
end

class NestedClass2
  include Module1
  def bar
    p @@shared
  end
end

NestedClass1.new.foo # => "hello world"
NestedClass2.new.bar # => "hello world"
```

Comment: Ah, cheers! I suppose I confused the two. Is there a way to share variables inside the same namespace? For instance if you're writing a gem and want to share the same variable between different files?